# Adding two numbers with callback funciton

Tags: go

What is the idiomatic approach for adding two numbers in this kind of manner
`Add(5)(3)` -> This is done in C# with delegate but I'm not sure what the right way to do that in Go since there's no `delegate`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do that in Go is not to do that.

Go's emphasis on performance and procedural nature means that functional patterns like currying are strongly anti-idiomatic. The only idiomatic way to add two numbers is Go is:

```
sum := 5 + 3
```

You could implement it with a function returning a function

```
func Add(val int) func(int) int {
    return func (other int) int {
        return val + other
    }
}
```

But you shouldn't. It adds complexity and slows down your program without any befit.

Answer (score 0):

Return a function that gets the first value from the the enclosing scope and the second number from an argument.

```
func Add(a int) func(int) int {
    return func(b int) int {
        return a + b
    }
}

fmt.Println(Add(3)(5)) // prints 8
```

None of this is idiomatic.  The idiomatic code is `3 + 5`.

Comment: Is it a callback ?? `A callback is a function which is passed as an argument to another function call`